# How often should donut tire be replaced?

Tags: spare-tire, donut

How often should a donut tire be replaced.... every 6 years, 10 years? Something else? I am not asking about a full sized spare tire, that is, one that is exactly like the four tires you normally drive on. I have a full size spare for my RV. It is carried outside on the back. I believe a donut tire is made to take up less space in the car trunk than a full size spare. I think a full size spare is one that you can put on, inflate more, and drive on safely for as many miles as any other tire you might buy. I believe the kind of tire called "donut" is a short-term tire meant to be used until you can get to a shop that will fix your old tire or sell you a new one.

I don't think this is a duplicate question unless the answer is that donut tires and full size tires should be replaced in exactly the same lengths of time and and that both are "spares" with the same characteristics.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please use the [edit] feature to clarify what you mean and give some vehicle details. Are you referring to years of non-use? What type of spare is it; hard rubber or inflated?

Comment: Although not the exact same question, this one may help you. [When do I need to replace my spare tire?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/5236/4939)

Comment: A donut tire that rides in the trunk for years, unused until now, when it was used to drive around 25 miles low speed. Not my tire so will have to wait til later to tell you if it is hard rubber or inflatable, and the car year and make. Thank you for responding.

Comment: @CharlieRB, sounds like a direct duplicate to me?  OP is asking when to replace a spare tire.

Comment: @Kelliann1, welcome to the site, and good question. So good it's already been asked!  I had a donut that was only 5-6 years old and I replaced it because the rubber was cracking badly.   It's a family vehicle and I didn't trust that rubber with my kids.

Comment: To those who say it was already answered, I don't really think so because I'm asking specifically about a donut tire, not a full size spare tire.

Comment: CharlieRB, to answer your question this is an inflatable donut, and it is on a 2001 Honda Accord. She purchased the car used in 2016. She will have to look on the side of it tomorrow to see what the date is. Thank you.

Comment: JPHi1618 thank you for telling me about your donut tire.

Comment: This question covers space-savers: https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/18293/675

Comment: @Kelliann1, there's no real difference between a "donut spare" and a regular spare.  One is just smaller than the other, but in my usage of the word, they are both tubeless air-filled tires made of the same rubber.  If you think you really have a more unique question, please elaborate.  I think the other questions give you good advice tho.

Comment: Thanks JPi6618 - that is exactly what I needed to know! So I am going to tell her that she should replace hers after 6 years. If this is incorrect please let me know.

Comment: Zaid,  your link was excellent because it allows for consideration of circumstances. This will guide her decision.

Comment: @Kelliann1 if the spare has never been used it will still be good after 6 years, tread depth and condition of the rubber are the important factors.

Comment: Thanks finleyarcher, that will help too. We will check the tread depth and also for cracks in the rubber.